# Outlook invitation update that doesn't change anything?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Using Outlook for Office 365 (2002 version) I just got an update to an event later today which appears to have rescheduled it from the previous time... to the exact same time.

[image: Thursday, October 15, 2020 12:00 PM-2:00 PM, (Thursday, October 15 2020 12:00 PM-2:00 PM)]

What's going on here?  Did something other than the time change, and Outlook just assumes that everything is a reschedule?  If so, how can I tell what really changed?

Or is there some aspect of the time which changed, but isn't currently displayed?

Comment: If you got a prior invitation, accepted, then the new invitation will normally be marked as "No Action Needed"   . The invite may say what has changed (e.g. Time or duration). Otherwise you need to review the appointment. I know from experience that this is not one of Outlook's best features.

Comment: @John - I've seen that "No action needed" notice before, although not very often.  This one did come in with new accept/tentative/decline buttons, though.

Comment: Was there a Red X mark on the invite area (top left of email)?  That means the same thing.

Comment: Seems a little strange. How does this invitation update show in your web mail? I tested in my Outlook and we could not update the same time as we set before and make update email show like that.